# Pandas selecting count of dates for each group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset containing information in following format.

```
Customerid ,customerinvoicedate, customerduedate, customrpaiddate, amount, cleared ?
1, 03-mar-2017, 02-june-2017, 03-april-2017, $200 ,   yes
2, 01-jan-2017, 11-dec-2017,  15-dec-2017,   $25000,  yes
1, 01-aug-2017, 05-oct-2017,  04-sep-2017, $100,    yes
```

I want to group customers and in each group for each invoice , I want to count number of invoices which was cleared before customerinvoicedate.
Now for customer 1 
while recording invoice dated on **01-aug-2017** it should check previous invoices which are cleared and count them. (here count is 1)

I tried this but doesn't seem to be working.

```
data.groupby(['Customerid']).apply(lambda x:np.count(data['customrpaiddate']<=x['customerinvoicedate']))
```

> it gives an error :- ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: It would be helpful to at least see sample data.

Comment: And also more specific information than "doesn't seem to be working"...

Comment: @AndrewL check out the updates.

Comment: @lanS I have updated the que with error. It anyway doesn't seem to be that simple groupby hence didn't post the error

Answer (score 1):

After you compare "paid date" and "due date", you can *sum* the boolean result (as True = 1 and False = 0) to count how many occurrences are `True`.
Since you want "the number of invoices cleared so far", you need to use cumulative sum:

```
cleared_invoices = df.groupby('Customerid').apply(lambda x: (x['customrpaiddate'] <= x['customerduedate']).cumsum())\
                                           .reset_index(level = 0, drop = True)\
                                           .rename('Cleared Invoices')

out = pd.concat([df, cleared_invoices], axis = 1)
```

which gives:

```
out
Out[137]: 
   Customerid  customerinvoicedate  customerduedate  customrpaiddate  \
0           1           03-03-2017       2017-02-06       2017-03-04   
1           2           01-01-2017       2017-11-12       2017-12-15   
2           1            01-8-2017       2017-05-10       2017-04-09   

      amount  cleared  Cleared Invoices  
0       $200      yes                 0  
1     $25000      yes                 0  
2       $100      yes                 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also need to run this in place for all the invoices and add new column.This is at customer level. What I want is at transaction level.

Comment: I have edited my answer accordingly. Let me know if this is what you were after.

Comment: for customer 2 the answer should be 0 since there are no previous cleared invoices.rest looks fine.Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are right: I didn't convert strings to dates so I was getting funky comparisons...If the answer solved your problem don't forget to upvote and accept :)

Comment: The Cleared Invoices column should be 0 0 1 since we have customer 1 getting invoice on "01-aug-2017" and same customer has cleared another invoice before "01-aug-2017" on "03-april-2017" .

Comment: Apologies, I guess because of firewall some edits were missed and answer got confused. The code gives your expected result

Comment: This won't work. This will check one to one mapping not all the dates < posting date.